# How does Bash assign the result of a command substitution to a variable when stdout of that command contains spaces?

Tags: bash, command-substitution

Lets say I have the following two Bash scripts:

```
# script1

var=$(./script2)
echo "$var"
```

```
# script2

echo "x y"
```

Running `./script1` outputs `x y`. As noted [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Substitution), "Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command". When applied to the execution of script1 I understand this as follows: As the standard output of `./script2` is `x y` the command substitution in script1 has to be replaced such that the corresponding line becomes `var=x y`. However, running

```
# script1 - command substitution replaced

var=x y
echo "$var"
```

would result in the expected error `./script1: line 3: y: command not found`. I know that `var='x y'` would work, but stdout of `./script2` is `x y` and not `'x y'`. So how does Bash do the replacement internally exactly?

Answer (score 1):

> how does Bash do the replacement internally exactly?

> becomes var=x y

The line is not re-parsed or re-evaled after the substitution. After the substitution, `x y` is one *word*, and it stays to be one word, and that one word is assigned to the variable.

Or, said differently, *word splitting expansion* (which splits one *word* into multiple *words*) is not performed on assignment.

> The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

When *you* write `x y` then these are *parsed* by the shell as two *words*. When shell takes the result of an expansion, it stays to be one word, *until* something splits it into multiple words.

Or a different counterexample:

```
var=$(echo '"a')
```

It's not the same as `var="a`. The line is not re-evaled, the result of command substitution `"a` is a *word*, a single token, that is assigned to `var`.

> how does Bash do the replacement internally exactly?

I think start from here https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/9439ce094c9aa7557a9d53ac7b412a23aa66e36b/subst.c#L3209 .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, something similar is claimed [here](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Expansions): "Only brace expansion, word splitting, and filename expansion can increase the number of words of the expansion; other expansions expand a single word to a single word."

Answer (score 0):

Section 2.9.1   (https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_01) describes the sequence of expansions performed on a simple command.  Step 4 is "Each variable assignment shall be expanded for tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal prior to assigning the value."  Note that "field splitting" is not mentioned here.  Basically, the right hand side of a variable assignment is *not* subject to field splitting.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, if `var1='x y'` and `var2=$(echo 'x y')`, then `var1` and `var2` are both assigned to the value `x y`, but `var1` by means of quote removal and `var2` by means of command substitution?

Comment: `var1=x y` consists of two words: `var1=x` and `y`.  The first word is saved for processing later (I'm basically quoting step 1 of section 2.9.1).  But `var1='x y'` is a single word, which is a variable assignment (and thus also saved for processing later).  The key to "saved for processing later" is that step 2, full word expansion (described in 2.6) is skipped, so field splitting does not happen.  The general rule to remember is simply that assignments aren't subject to splitting.  But you should quote the RHS anyway!